# Difference between j2me and Symbian

Tags: java-me, symbian

I wanna to know in detail what is the difference between symbian OS and j2me.Which is best to use

Comment: For the purposes of programming? J2ME is a version of Java, and typically the phones' OS isn't written it. Symbian is native, as are the apps for it (or Python). Of course, the best to use is the one on the phone you have or want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It al depends on what you are trying to build. If you need to support multiple phones with different OS, then JavaME is probably what you want.

If you need to develop full native applications for Nokia phones with Symbian OS, then Symbian is probably what you want.

Although JavaME is not platform independent (you will probably have to have multiple versions your APP for phones sharing the same features) you **will** get some degree of independence that will make your life easier if you are targeting multiple platforms.

Comment: Thank.I am working on game Marble Maze for Nokia N97 i.e for symbian OS.But i am using j2me.SO i think because of this i can't able to get proper output based on performance.SO do you used j2me and symbian? what is difference in there api.Which is more advance and benifiacial for my app